# Movement Object and Comparing indetical Vector3 in ArrayList

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing a C# script on Unity 3D.
I'm working on pathfinding now.
The path has been found correctly in the Array List and the Object can move according to the path with a constant speed.
Then, I want to improvise, where when the path found is a straight line, the object will increase its speed. Meanwhile, when the path turns the object will reduce its speed again.
Here, I don't know how to group between straight and turning paths in an arrayList.
Thankyou for helping me :)
This is the code :

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

public abstract class Unit : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region public variables
    public GameObject Astar;
    public bool drawGizmos = false;
    protected float gravity = 9.8f;
    public Transform target;
    public Transform NPC;
    public Vector3 lastTargetPosition;
    public float movementSpeed;
    public float rotationSpeed = 85;
    protected float distanceToPath = 1;
    public Vector2 currentPosition = new Vector2(0, 0);
    protected int spacesMoved = 0;
    // Default action times to 5 second interval
    protected float period = 1f;
    protected float nextActionTime = 1f;
    protected bool isSafeToUpdatePath = false;
    protected int pathFoundCount = 0;
    protected bool isMoving = false;
    protected bool isTargetReached = false;
    #endregion

    #region member variables
    public Vector3[] m_path;
    protected int m_targetIndex;
    protected CharacterController m_characterController;
    private Node lastNodePosition;
    private List<Node> lastPositionNeighbors;
    private Vector3 m_lastKnownPosition;
    private Quaternion m_lookAtRotation;
    private GridSystem m_grid;
    private Coroutine lastRoutine = null;
    private bool preventExtraNodeUpdate = false;
    public Stopwatch timer;
    #endregion

    public virtual void Awake()
    {
        timer = new Stopwatch();
        if (Astar != null)
            m_grid = Astar.GetComponent<GridSystem>();
    }

    public virtual void Start()
    {
        m_characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        timer.Reset();
        timer.Start();
        PathRequestManager.RequestPath(transform.position, target.position, OnPathFound);
        lastTargetPosition = target.position;
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("NPC Position : " + transform.position);
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Target Position : " + target.position);
    }

    public virtual void Update()
    {

        if (Time.time > nextActionTime) //update path setiap 1f
        {
            nextActionTime += period;
            isSafeToUpdatePath = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isSafeToUpdatePath = false;
        }

        //If we don't check !isMoving the AI may get stuck waiting to update the grid for nextActionTime.

        if (target.position != lastTargetPosition)
        {
            isMoving = true;
            UpdateNodePosition();
            UpdatePath();
            UpdateRotation();
        }

        lastTargetPosition = target.position;

    }

    public void UpdatePath()
    {
        lastNodePosition.walkable = Walkable.Passable;
        PathRequestManager.RequestPath(transform.position, target.position, OnPathFound);
    }

    public virtual void OnPathFound(Vector3[] newPath, bool pathSuccessful)
    {
        if (pathSuccessful)
        {
            pathFoundCount++;
            m_path = newPath;
            m_targetIndex = 0;

            // Stop coroutine if it is already running.
            if (lastRoutine != null)
                StopCoroutine(lastRoutine);

            lastRoutine = StartCoroutine(FollowPath());
        }
    }

    public float time;
    public virtual IEnumerator FollowPath()
    {
        Vector3 currentPath = m_path[0];

        while (true)
        {

            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, currentPath) < distanceToPath)
            {
                m_targetIndex++;

                // If we are done with path.
                if (m_targetIndex >= m_path.Length)
                {
                    timer.Stop();
                    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Time Move : " + timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                    isMoving = false;
                    yield break;
                }


                currentPath = m_path[m_targetIndex];
            }
            float Distance = Vector3.Distance(NPC.transform.position, target.transform.position);
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Distance : " + Distance);
            // Occurs each frame
            //move follow path
            UpdatePosition(currentPath);

            yield return null;

        }
    }


    public virtual void UpdatePosition(Vector3 destination)
    {
        Node node = m_grid.NodeFromWorldPoint(transform.position);

        Vector3 direction = destination - transform.position;
        movementSpeed = 1;
        transform.Translate(direction.normalized * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Speed NPC : " + movementSpeed);

    }

    public virtual void UpdateRotation()
    {
        m_lastKnownPosition = target.transform.position;
        m_lookAtRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(m_lastKnownPosition - transform.position);

        if (transform.rotation != m_lookAtRotation)
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, m_lookAtRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }


    public void UpdateNodePosition()
    {
        Node node = m_grid.NodeFromWorldPoint(transform.position);

        if (isMoving == false)
        {
            lastPositionNeighbors = m_grid.GetNeighbours(node);
            foreach (Node n in lastPositionNeighbors)
            {
                if (n.walkable != Walkable.Impassable)
                    n.walkable = Walkable.Blocked;
            }
            node.walkable = Walkable.Blocked;
            lastNodePosition = node;
            currentPosition = new Vector2(node.gridX, node.gridY);
            return;
        }

        if (lastNodePosition != null && isMoving)
        {
            preventExtraNodeUpdate = false;
            lastPositionNeighbors = m_grid.GetNeighbours(node);
            lastNodePosition.walkable = Walkable.Passable;
            if (lastPositionNeighbors != null)
                foreach (Node n in lastPositionNeighbors)
                {
                    if (n.walkable != Walkable.Impassable)
                        n.walkable = Walkable.Passable;
                }
            if (!node.Equals(lastNodePosition))
                spacesMoved++;
        }
        else
        {
            node.walkable = Walkable.Blocked;
            lastNodePosition = node;
            currentPosition = new Vector2(node.gridX, node.gridY);
        }



    }

    public void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (!drawGizmos)
            return;

        if (m_path != null)
        {
            for (int i = m_targetIndex; i < m_path.Length; i++)
            {
                Gizmos.color = Color.black;
                Gizmos.DrawCube(m_path[i], Vector3.one);

            }
        }
    }

}
```

[This screenshot after running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vRVZ.png)

Comment: Can you give an example of what your path array would look like in an example where the path is not straight. I'm having trouble understanding what it means for the path to be straight. From what I see it seems like you are moving an object in a grid. Do you want to slow down whenever you make a turn on the grid?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19eSYUrc4d_YAE79gLZyabD7LyrYzsxJn/view?usp=sharing     ,,, @SethSetse thank you for your response, from that picture I want when the object finds a straight road its speed will increase, but when the road turns its speed will decrease again. And yes i use Grid for the representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. It looks to me like all that you have to do in order to determine if you are on a curved path is to check if the next step you are going to take is directly in front of the player. You can do this in your UpdatePosition function. Just check if the direction you are about to move in has the same x or z position. Assuming that y is up and all points on your grid have the same y position. In the case that you are moving horizontally, x will stay the same, and in the case that you are moving vertically, z will stay the same. Or vice versa.

```
public virtual void UpdatePosition(Vector3 destination)
{
    Node node = m_grid.NodeFromWorldPoint(transform.position);

    Vector3 direction = destination - transform.position;
    if(destination.x == transform.position.x || destination.z == transform.position.z)
    {
        //Direction is staying the same
        movementSpeed = 1f;
    }else{
        movementSpeed = 0.5f;
    }
    transform.Translate(direction.normalized * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Speed NPC : " + movementSpeed);

}
```

You should be able to customize the movement speed however you want from there. IF you're having issues still after this, try printing out the (x,y,z) components of the destination and the transform and see where they are similar when the path is straight and what changes when the path is curved. The code above assumes the y never changes.

Comment: I have tried and it worked, but in addition .ToString after .position.z .. Thank you very much..  :) @Seth Setse

Comment: can someone help, I get a problem when vector3 is negative. operator == don't think it's equal. What should I do ?

Comment: @DiahNovianti Can you post a new question and explain in more detail?